# How to buy US saving bonds if I am not American?

Tags: united-states, bonds

I am not an American citizen, but I hold a social security number because of an H1B visa.

I would like to purchase some U.S. saving bonds, but I currently don't live in the U.S. How can I buy those bonds and how does the tax situation work since I am not living there?

Answer (score 4):

In order to buy US Savings Bonds, you need an SSN and to meet any of these [conditions](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eebuy.htm):

- United States citizen, whether you live in the US or abroad
- United States resident
- Civilian employee of the United States, no matter where you live

It sounds like you don't qualify.  If you did qualify, you could buy them online at http://www.treasurydirect.gov.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to open a Treasury Direct account, you will be asked to declare that you are a U.S. person according to IRS. Refer to this document for definition of U.S. person: https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/classification-of-taxpayers-for-us-tax-purposes.